# Mongoose instance method not able to access properties from document typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My interface for the model

```
export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    photo: string;
    password: string;
    passwordConfirm: string | undefined;
    correctPassword: (candidatePassword: string, userPassword: string) => boolean;
    changedPasswordAfter: (timestamp: string) => Date;
}
```

My model -

```
export const User = model<IUser>('user', userSchema);
```

My instance method -

```
userSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function (timestamp: string): Date {
    if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
        //
    }

    return false;
};
```

The error shown by typescript - Property 'passwordChangedAt' does not exist on type `Document<any>`

Why is this? How do I solve this?

Comment: I think you have a typo: `passwordChangedAt` in the method vs. `changedPasswordAfter` in the interface. If not, please include the schema

Comment: Yes, that is 1 thing but even after fixing that the code does not work. If you notice in Property 'passwordChangedAt' does not exist on type 'Document<any>, look at <any>. I believe that's the root of the problem but I don't know how to fix it.